# Passing multiple variables back from a single function?

Tags: c++, function, variables

I have an assignment (see below for question) for a beginners c++ class, where i am asked to pass 2 values back from a single function. I am pretty sure of my understanding of how to use functions and the general structure of what the program should be, but i am having trouble fingin how to pass two variables back to "main" from the function.

Assignment:
Write a program that simulates an airplane race. The program will display a table showing the speed in km/hour and distance in km traveled by two airplanes every second until one of them has gone 10 kilometers.

These are the requirements for the program:

-The program will use a function that has the following parameters: time and acceleration.

-**The function will pass back two data items: speed and distance.**

Comment: Two things that can help you, together or interdependently: Structures and references.

Comment: Either (1) return a structure, (2) pass arguments by reference (3) pass arguments by pointer into a function. (1) is clear but value copy can impact performance. (2) tends to obfsucate (IMHO), (3) is cute but perhaps I'm old-fashioned.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I would expect most optimizing compilers to elide the copy for option 1 in most circumstances. I see no good reason to go with pointers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options (well, three really, but I'm leaving pointers out).

1. Take references to output arguments and assign them within the function.
2. Return a data structure which contains all of the return values.

Which option is best depends on your program. If this is a one off function that isn't called from many places then you may chose to use option #1. I assume by "speed" you mean the "constant velocity" which is reached after "time" of acceleration.

```
void calc_velocity_profile(double accel_time, 
                           double acceleration, 
                           double &out_velocity,   // these last two are 
                           double &out_distance);  // assigned in the function
```

If this is a more general purpose function and/or a function which will be called by many clients I would probably prefer option #2.

```
struct velocity_profile {
    double velocity;
    double distance;
};

velocity_profile calc_velocity_profile(double accel_time, double acceleration);
```

Everything being equal, I prefer option 1.  Given the choice, I like a function which returns a value instead of a function which mutates its input.

Comment: Yep, I would approve the second second solution as you don't loose the "value returning function" semantic. I would add `your_data_structure`  should be a POD type to be sure it's construction/copy is a quick process.

Comment: Pointer are a valid option, provide a feature/usage pattern that you cant otherwise get. But unfortunately are shunned/not up-voted because we like to keep newbies away from pointers because they will hurt themselves because pointers are evil. Gotta love SO.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: For most cases (including this one) they are inferior to taking references because references cannot be null.  Why take a pointer when you have references in a situation like this?  I am all for newbies learning all there is to know about pointers (really, I've been mugged by the crowd on this one as well), but I don't see the use case here.

Comment: @EdS. Well, I would say references are *safer*, more *syntactically pleasing*, and more *transparent*. However, pointers do provide a *super-set* of the functionality references do, so I think saying that they are *inferior* is simply wrong. Pointers are often still used in situations such as this, since output reference params do not scale well when designing APIs past a couple of entries, especially when certain instances of client code might only be meaningfully interested in one output. In this case, using references requires excess boiler plate variable setup before the function call.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: I did say inferior in *most* cases, not all. I suppose I'm not sure what your point is though; what additional boilerplate do references require?  You'll still need a valid chunk of memory for your pointers to refer to, and you're going to have to allocate that *somewhere*.  No different than the references.  I suppose my point was that you use pointers when you *need* pointers.  If you don't need them then references are a better option. They provide a bit more safety, and like anything, you should be using the right tool for the job.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: I'm a systems guy, most of the code I write is low level by today's standards, but I can't say I use pointers often in C++.

Comment: @EdS. The point was that you can provide NULL for certain params to such functions (and only assign if non-null inside the function), so that you only need to declare variables you are interested in. I've seen this pattern a lot in many APIs. I am astounded how many comments it takes to communicate this. A concrete example in a modern api: [`ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This kind of optional in/out params API cannot be done with references. This is common when writing API/frameworks, not so much in client code

Comment: @PreetKukreti: I'm astounded that I have to keep repeating that everything I say is in the context of this question, wherein neither of the two outputs are optional.  However, I don't agree that functions which take a large number of optional output parameters is a great API design (do you have fun writing Win32 code? I know I don't). "Common" isn't synonymous with "Good".

Comment: @EdS. The title of the question is "Passing multiple variables back from a single function?". I have shown 3 methods, 1 of which, while not necessarily the best in every situation, does make sense in others. There are no silver bullets, and in particular, learning this pattern may simply be helpful when reading code, not just writing it. Writing unnecessarily to all members of a large struct is a performance penalty in some situations, where depending on out param validity, the function can early-out, with the NULL params providing intent or registering interest in only certain outputs.

Comment: @PreetKukreti: Well, I suppose if you only read the title and not the question itself and not, you know, any of the relevant bits, your continued attempts at convincing me of... I don't even know what... are justified.  I never even disagreed with you, not sure what you're going on about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43166/discussion-between-preet-kukreti-and-ed-s)

Answer (score 3):

**2017 Update:** This is discussed in the C++ Core Guidelines :

*[F.21 To return multiple "out" values, prefer returning a tuple or struct](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out-multi)*

However, I would lean towards returning a struct over a tuple due to named, order-independent access that is encapsulated and reusable as a explicit strong type.

In the special case of returning a `bool` and a `T`, where the `T` is only filled if the `bool` is `true` , consider returning a `std::optional<T>`. See [this CPPCon17 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkDEzfpdcSg&feature=youtu.be&t=1737) for an extended discussion.

---

**Struct version:**

```
struct SpeedInfo{
    float speed;
    float distance;
};

SpeedInfo getInfo()
{
    SpeedInfo si;
    si.speed = //...
    si.distance = //...
    return si;
}
```

The benefit of this is that you get an encapsulated type with named access.

---

**Reference version:**

```
void getInfo(float& speed, float& distance)
{
    speed = //...
    distance = //...
}
```

You have to pass in the output vars:

```
float s;
float d;
getInfo(s, d);
```

---

**Pointer version:**

```
void getInfo(float* speed, float* distance)
{
    if(speed)
    {
        *speed = //...
    }
    if(distance)
    {
        *distance= //...
    }
}
```

Pass the memory address of the output variable:

```
float s;
float d;
getInfo(&s, &d);
```

Pointer version is interesting because you can just pass a `nullptr`/`NULL`/`0` for things you aren't interested in; this can become useful when you are using such a function that potentially takes a lot of params, but are not interested in all the output values. e.g:

```
float d;
getInfo(nullptr, &d);
```

This is something which you cant do with references, although they are safer.

Answer (score 1):

There is already such a data structure in C++ that is named as std::pair. It is declared in header `<utility>`. So the function could look the following way

```
std::pair<int, int> func( int time, int acceleration )
{
   // some calculations

   std::pair<int, int> ret_value;
   ret_value.first = speed_value;
   ret_value.second = distance_value;

   return ( ret_value );
}
```